# How to Remove white spaces or Blank lines from jdom

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, xml-parsing, jdom

I am using XMLOutputter class for writing Document object's contents into a xml file.

But i am facing below problem: 
when i delete any child node, it creates blank line in Document object and while saving its contents into xml file, it displays blank line in xml file as well.

So it means that if i perform delete operation 10 time and saved its contents then there would be 10 blank lines in the xml file.

I went through the below links. These links suggest to use below api:

1. http://www.jdom.org/pipermail/jdom-interest/2003-November/013035.html

this link suggest:

```
XMLOutputter fmt = new XMLOutputter();
fmt.setTextTrim(true);  //this would remove all spaces
fmt.setIndent("  ");    // this will do indentation
fmt.setNewlines(true);
```

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/xmljava/section5.html

   SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();

   Document doc = sb.build(new File(argv[0]));

   XMLOutputter xo = new XMLOutputter();

   xo.setTrimAllWhite(true);

   xo.output(doc, System.out);

Can some one help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: 3. Even api document also suggest some api "setTrimAllWhite" but it seems that now it is deprecated. 
http://jplist.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sf/jplist/output/XmlOutputter.html

Comment: eg.
<parent>
<child_1>
</child_1>
<child_2>
</child_2>
<child_3>
</child_3>
</parent>

if i delete node <child_2> then result will be:

<parent>
<child_1>
</child_1>
------>>  Blank line
<child_3>
</child_3>
</parent>

I want to save the Document object as xml file without blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to remove whitespace/blank lines, or do you want the output to be formatted nicely with correct indents etc.?

To get nice indenting use the ['pretty'](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#getPrettyFormat%28%29) format?

```
xo.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
```

to strip all unnecessary whitespace use Format.getCompactFormat()

rolfl

Comment: i have found the same answer from link: http://osdir.com/ml/java.jdom.genera2004-12msg00084.html                              OR XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

Comment: Actually, you would have found the answer in the Javadoc too, right at the top: http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html